# Failed to use 'sudo systemctl status apache2'

Tags: sockets, apache2, port80

I'm currently trying to install and run apache2, I could install it but not configure it using 'sudo systemctl status apache2' and this error appears:

```
systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
apachectl[16656]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to ad>
apachectl[16656]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to ad>
apachectl[16656]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
 apachectl[16656]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
apachectl[16646]: The Apache error log may have more information.
systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

So, when I googled about this error I found maybe my port 80 was alredy been used and tried 'ss --listening --tcp --numeric --processes' to find out what is using port 80/tcp, I also kind of messed up using this command sudo kill -9, and now but none of the outputs say 80.

Thank you so much for your valuable help.

Comment: Hi, this question is not about programming and so it probably belongs to other StackExchange site (likely ServerFault.com). From the log trace `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to ad>` I guess issue is that Apache is being put on port which is taken by something else running on the machine.

Comment: yes, I found people saying that and I tried to use sudo kill -9, but It doesn't work still, and I think maybe I messed up thinks because now I can't see what's at the port 80 anymore

Answer (score 1):

**Hi**, This error is most probably caused by another process in the port you are trying to run apache on. Or it can also be the fact that your firewall (`ufw`)
might be blocking apache.

To check if the firewall is blocking apache run: `sudo ufw app list` in your teminal. If apache is in the list then it might be another process. If apache is not in your app list run this command: `sudo ufw allow apache2` and then restart apache using `sudo systemctl start apache2`.

Hope this was helpful